# How to reassign Home and End keys using Windows keyboard on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am new to Mac and found that the only convenient keyboard for me is a Windows full keys keyboard without the numeric pad (MS gaming keyboard).  Would it be possible to make the Home and End keys behaving exactly as in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyRemap4MacBook worked fine for me. One needs to choose "For PC users", then use PC style Home/End, then reload XML